# La Ruta Maya in 3 weeks: reasonable?

Tags: mexico, central-america, itineraries

Next winter I would like to go to Central or South America. I'm already looking for some possible itineraries for approximately 3 or 4 weeks. I found La Ruta Maya which sounds pretty interesting. Can this journey be traveled in 3 weeks without skipping too much interesting stuff?

Comment: Do you want to do it independently or in an organized tour?

Comment: I would prefer the independent way if possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a few searches. [This UK travel company](http://www.exodus.co.uk/holidays/aur/overview) has a 15-day itinerary. [This regional summary](http://gocentralamerica.about.com/od/sampleitineraries/p/LaRutaMaya.htm) has 7 stops each for a day or two with some possible side trips. So it certainly seems reasonable that you could create your own route and spend a very enjoyable 21 days.